# Cant get Flask-SocketIO, uWSGI and NGINX to work

Tags: nginx, flask, websocket, uwsgi, flask-socketio

Hi guys I've been trying to sort this out for a few weeks now and I'm at a complete loss.

I have a flask app that is running successfully as a REST API for my applications. I have decided to add web sockets to my API so I can trigger updates in my applications should my database get updated or on certain events.

What I've added to my flask application:

```
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit, send
socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins="*")
```

The uwsgi.ini file:

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi:app

master = true
processes = 5
http-websockets = true <--- added this
socket = fzInternal_API.sock
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true

die-on-term = true
logto = /home/brett/fzInternal_API/fzInternal_API.log
```

my wsgi.py file:

```
from fzInternal_API import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #app.run()
    socketio.run(app, port=5000, host='0.0.0.0')
```

my NGINX confing file in sites enabled:

```
server {
    listen 5000;
    server_name 10.10.10.3:5000;


    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/home/brett/fzInternal_API/fzInternal_API.sock;
        uwsgi_ignore_client_abort on;
    }

    location /socket.io {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_buffering off;
        add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "http://10.10.10.3" always;
        add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" "true" always;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_pass http://10.10.10.3:5000;
        proxy_hide_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin;
        proxy_hide_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials;
        proxy_hide_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers;
    }

}
```

my Systemd service file to start it all:

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI instance to serve fzInternal_API
After=network.target

[Service]
User=brett
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/brett/fzInternal_API
Environment="PATH=/home/brett/fzInternal_API/bin"
ExecStart=/home/brett/fzInternal_API/bin/uwsgi --ini /home/brett/fzInternal_API/fzInternal_API.ini

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Now I initially had a heap of CORS errors that I couldn't figure out but somehow got around them by tweaking the NGINX file (nothing I done in the flask configuration worked) but now when I try to connect to the websocket server with a simple html file (hosted on the same server in another virtual server instance) I just get alternating 500 (Internal Server Error) and  400 (Bad Request) errors.

Nothing in the logs seems to indicate anything so Im at a loss.
Btw the normal flask end point still work perfectly.

Comment: Are you reading the Flask-SocketIO documentation with regards to deploying with uWSGI? You don't seem to be following the rules at all.

Comment: I seem to have all the requirements covered from the documentation? 
location /socket.io {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000/socket.io;
    }`

Comment: I'm talking about uWSGI, not nginx.

Comment: ahh ok so this command ?
uwsgi --http :5000 --gevent 1000 --http-websockets --master --wsgi-file app.py --callable app

Comment: Is there a better way to achieve a production  flask based API with both REST end points and Websocket end points? I'm completely lost trying to set this up now, the frustrating thing is it works perfectly on the flask development server.

Comment: The only ways I have personally tested are those that I put in the documentation. Gunicorn is easier to deploy than uWSGI, maybe try that instead.

Comment: Cheers Miguel, I'll take a look at Gunicorn.
I've just installed eventlet and I'm using the socketio.run(app) method to run for now, this should suffice for the time being and I'll just use Nginx for my front end application.

Comment: In case it isn't clear, socketio.run(app) paired with eventlet and nginx as reverse proxy is a 100% ptoduction ready configuration. If you've got that working, you can really stop there, this is a very good set up.

Comment: Cheers Miguel, I don't have NGINX reverse proxying yet, I'm just invoking with python app.py and connecting direct atm. I've never used NGINX before so I'm still learning the config etc.